# Windows Workgroup & AD password Sync

Tags: windows, active-directory, workgroup

Does anyone know a tool that can sync passwords with users of a Windows Workgroup with Active Directory Users passwords?

Both servers being: Windows 2008 R2

Comment: If this is a one-time sync please see [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/346898/how-to-migrate-windows-users-and-retain-passwords), else you might be stuck implementing your own [Password Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721882(v=vs.85).aspx) to produce the desired behavior.

Comment: Not a 1 time operation but something we would like to run daily?

Comment: Please read the other question and the MSDN regarding Password Filters.  A Password Filter can trigger specific actions at the time of password change within Active Directory.  You would not need to "run daily" a sync operation.

Comment: Yes I see. Ideally we would want to store the username and new password of the changed user account in a DB for sync'ing to other systems.

Comment: Workgroup and AD Account name are diferrent..?