# Users & Groups replication in a workgroup environment

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, user-accounts

Good Day,

I have two servers running windows server 2008 R2
Also i have same users and groups in a workgroup environment on both servers
how can i replicate all users&groups on server 1 to server 2 
that when whenever i add or modify a user or group on server 1 will be also applied on server2
is it possible by using a certain tool ??

Kindly hope you can answer my question

Answer (score 4):

The built-in functionality to do what you're looking for is, very likely, Active Directory.

I wrote a [script that creates local users and groups based on the list on another computer](https://serverfault.com/a/33742/7200) but that's not actually replication-- that's just copying the names of the users and groups and group membership. Each machine has a unique machine SID and, therefore, each group and user will have a unique SID on each machine, irrespective of their names being identical.

There's also no native mechanism to handle password synchronization other than Active Directory. If a user's password is changed on one server the change won't be replicated to the other.

If you want the machines to have users and groups with the same SIDs and to have password replication then Active Directory is what you're looking for.